# How to randomize the value of class on body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, document-body

I have an array with some strings and I choose a random one. I need this value on `<body class="MY_STRING">`. How can I do this?

I tried something like:

```
document.write('<body class="' + my_string + '">')
```

but didn't work.

**Update:**
The question is misconceived. My doubt was not about random elements. This question explains better (and contais the answer that i need):

[Setting document.body.className as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125993/setting-document-body-classname-as-a-variable)

I did not knew how to explain the problem. Ty for answers.

Comment: Start by searching for how to get a random value from an Array. Once you have that, then search for how to add a class to an element.

Comment: This is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283511/how-to-add-a-class-to-body-tag

Comment: @bitoiu that implies that he is using jquery.

Comment: the last solution uses native JS, just not the accepted answer.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ he is a she (that's why there are 6 answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var classes = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'black', 'purple'],
    randomClass = classes[getRandomInt(0, classes.length - 1)];

document.body.className = randomClass;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ9J3/2/

Comment: Better to use `.className = "foo"` to set the class of an element. It's shorter, faster and doesn't have issues in old IE.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write` as it overwrites the DOM.
Use:

```
document.body.setAttribute('class',my_string);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(body)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your class list array. We will random one class then.

```
var classList = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
```

Then get the random key for that array:

```
var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length);
```

Now, select  tag and add random class attribute from classList array:

```
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
bodyTag[0].setAttribute("class", classList[randomKey]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsb5N/)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the class value after the fact using a script tag.

```
<body id="layout">
   <div>stuff</div>

   <script type="text/javascript>
       document.getElementById("layout").className = "my_string";
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: No need to add an ID to the body. Just do `document.body.className`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX) + MIN;
 document.body.className = "body" + random;
```

Put the above code wherever you want it to happen. Must be after DOM load.

Create CSS classes with names body1, body6 etc... (Depending on your MIN and MAX)